# Can a floor made of copper pennies produce a static electric shock?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, everyday-life

A friend is going to install thousands of pennies in a mosaic layout to be used as flooring in his home.

Can this floor produce a static electric shock when walking on it?

Is it possible to prevent this with a suitable choice of building materials to surround or underlay the pennies? For example, putting them on wood, on cement, or sealing them somehow?

Answer (score 1):

No static hazard but there is an increased chance of an electric shock with faulty electrical equipment since it may result in a better ground contact through bare feet. There is also the possibility that he might get some interference effects with things like TVs because it is effectively a reflective metal floor. However, most likely everything will be OK

Answer (score 1):

If the pennies are guaranteed to make electrical contact with each other, no static charge will build up. However, the pennies will probably be embedded in a matrix of some non-conductive material, and friction with this matrix will allow a static charge to build up. Even if the pennies are touching at the time of installation, oxidation will eventually produce a copper oxide layer between individual pennies, especially since they only touch at a very small point.